# What 3.5 book has the body of power feat?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, books

I remember a previous DM of mine mentioned that he had a book where characters add body augmentations like power of body or power of mind and i was wondering if anyone knows what book it is from?

Comment: Nothing is coming up in the [official feat list](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/lists/feats/), so it's not a first-party WotC book. Any more clues? There were very many 3rd party books published for 3.x, and it's even possible that it was a netbook…

Comment: Well, the Eberron Campaign Setting had rules - which I cannot remember in detail off the top of my head, since I never used them - for implanting enchanted dragonshards in a body and gaining a benefit that way. And I remember there was one book that had 'Grafts' as a magic item type, and they were quite literally grafted onto the flesh, but I can't remember which book it was.

Comment: Check with this DM for the accurate names if you can. That would be very useful. I remember vaguely Power of mind..but it was something psionic

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can find with "Body of Power" as the actual name was an ability for a homebrew class called a Blaster, published on the Giant in the Playground forums. It didn't seem to be all that well received, either.

http://www.giantitp.com/forums/archive/index.php?t-227306.html (See Level 14)